# How to scale a layer with gradient?

Tags: gimp, resize

For a web game logo I keep around a Gimp file 1024x1024-logo.xcf which has 3 layers:

1. Text (the game name)
2. Picture of 2 playing cards
3. Blue background as a linear gradient

Now I have received a new requirement to provide a new logo at the dimensions 392x240.

Using Image -> Scale Image with those dimensions would give me a skewed image:

[image]

If not for the gradient background, I would better issue:

1. Image -> Scale Image to 240x240 (too keep proportions)
2. Image -> Canvas Size to 392x340 and center the image

But I don't know how to scale the backround gradient, any suggestions for Gimp please?

Comment: check this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12841/in-gimp-how-to-scale-up-image-without-scaling-layers?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do (if I'm understanding correctly):

- Duplicate the original and scale it down to 240*240 (depends on what you want the font to look like in the end)
- Make a new image at 392*240
- In the new image, add a layer and make the gradient using the original's (1024*1024) colours (using the colour select tool and the gradient tool).
- Copy the top two layers of the 240 image and paste them onto new layers of the 392 image, and play around with the positioning.

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using an actual gradient layer will scale the gradient to whatever size you drag and drop it to.

Change canvas size.

Create a new gradient layer nearly identical to this.

Put the image and text on top.

To get this two colour gradient, select any two colour linear gradient and change each colour to the one closest to top and the other closest to the bottom.